# what operation repeated $n$ times results in the addition operator?

Tags: arithmetic, hyperoperation

I had a difficult time in phrasing my question. But I was wondering if there is an operation that, when repeated n times, results in the addition operator. Same way as repeating addition n times results in the multiplication operator, and repeating multiplication n times results in the exponentiation operator etc.

So $n$ times addition of a number $x$ results in $x\times n$.

And $n$ times multiplication of a number $x$ results in $x^n$

Then my question is $n$ times ...what... results into the number $x+n$.

Let's call this operator: $@$.

For example, the following would then hold:

$$a\times a=a^2$$

$$a+a=a\times 2$$

$$a@a=a+2$$

My question is, does it make any sense thinking of such an operator, is there anything known about it, can it be followed through even further like $a\sim a = a@2$?

Comment: A kind of unitary addition maybe ? Define $a @ a := a + 1$.

Comment: This question seems a bit ill-defined, because the natural operation that is recursed to get addition is a unitary operation (increment operator), so knowing only that $a@a=a+2$, you could define any number of operations that satisfy that condition, like $f(a, b) = a + 2$.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2153809/is-this-a-new-operation

Answer (score 26):

You want an operator $@$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb N$,
$$\underbrace{a\mathop @a\mathop @\ldots\mathop @ a}_n = a+n.$$

The first problem with this is the case $n=1$ (not to mention $n=0$), where you demand $a=a+1$ (in analogy to $a = a\cdot 1$ and $a=a^1$).
So we need drop the case $n=1$.

The next problem is that we did not specify whether $@$ should be associative. And if not: Do we mean $(a\mathop @ a)\mathop @ a = a+3$ or $a\mathop @ (a\mathop @ a) = a+3$? Let's attempt to actually achieve associativity.
Then we need 
$$\begin{align}a\mathop @a&=a+2 \\
(a+n)\mathop @a &= a+n+1&\text{for }n\ge 2\\
a\mathop @(a+n) &= a+n+1&\text{for }n\ge 2\\
\end{align}$$
This in fact allows us to extract a complete definition for $@$:
$$a\mathop @ b=\begin{cases}
\max\{a,b\}+1&\text{if }a\ne b\\
a+2&\text{if }a=b\end{cases} $$
(where the cases with $b=a\pm 1$ are irrelevant).

Comment: not sure if I demand a = a + 1, I am not sure what the identity element is yet. I would call the identity element of the operator @ simply id, then a = a @ id. For the @ operator I would not know yet what a @ 1 would be

Comment: It is nice to see $\max$ here, since $+$ distributes over it. And actually, it seems that $c +(a\mathop @ b) = (c+a) \mathop @ (c+ b)$.

Comment: It's worth noting that $a\times a\times a\times\dots$ should technically be interpreted as $1\times a\times a\times a\times\dots$, so the equivalent for $n=1$ would actually be $1@a=a+1$, not $a=a+1$ (or perhaps a different number in place of $1$).

Comment: Indeed, for your definition, the "identity" in question is actually $-\infty$, because $(-\infty)@a=a@(-\infty) = a+1$.

Comment: @GlenO Cool observation. So $a^n=1\,\underbrace{\times a\ldots\times a}_n$, $a\times n = 0\,\underbrace{+a\ldots+a}_n$, $a+n=(-\infty)\,\underbrace{\mathop @a\ldots\mathop @a}_n$.

Comment: Yes, although you need to be careful because $a+0\neq -\infty$. But you can't really fix that - the relation requires $n\geq 1$.

Comment: @GlenO : I think, the term "neutral element" is appropriate for the $1$ in multiplication: $1 \times a \times a \cdots$ , for the $0$ in addition $ 0 + a + a + \cdots $ and then the $ -\infty$ in zeration $ (-\infty) @ a @ a @ \cdots $. Note that are consecutively $ 1= \log_a(a)$, $ 0 = \log_a(1)$, $(-\infty)=\log_a(0)$. (The latter should be understood as a limit) Surely this can in some way meaningfully be extrapolated to the other direction in the hyper-operator-hierarchy (... ctd...)

Comment: (...ctd...) I also think, a significant term in that hierarchy-of-operations is that of an *"absorbing element"*: multiplication $0 \times a \times \cdots \to 0$, for addition $(-\infty) + a + \cdots = (-\infty) $, for exponentiation/ raising to power $1^a \cdots =1 $ where I do not have an idea, what would be the *"absorbing element"* for *zeration* ...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms - I'm pretty sure that $1$ is the absorbing element for all of the higher tetration-type operators, so I don't think the reasoning can be applied in that way. In fact, I'd suggest that that sequence is more closely related to the binary operation sequence based on $a\times b=e^{\ln a+\ln b}$. You can define an operation not unlike our $@$ operator (but subtly different) as $a\oplus b = \log_c{c^a+c^b}$ for some base $c$. In this case, $a\oplus a=a+\log_c 2$ and $a\oplus a\oplus a=a+\log_c 3$.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes** there is.

The successor $s$ function do that where:

$$\forall n\in\mathbb Z,\quad s(n)=n+1$$

and $s(0)=0$.

You can have more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function).

Thanks to a comment, you also might be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation).

Though you can not define this operator as a binary relation as you would like it to be defined.

Comment: The OP is looking for a dyadic operator, and $n$ incremented $n$ times doesn't yield $n+2$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think this is the operation the OP is looking for, even though he is asking for a binary operation. His last questions suggests he wants go on to be interested in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation - perhaps that link should be edited into this answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker: no, this is not the only post on this topic by the OP. He wants a dyadic operator, following the same pattern as $+$ and $\times$ and ^.

Comment: @YvesDaoust OK I didn't know the history. Maybe he'll find this answer useful anyway.

Comment: @EthanBolker: I couldn't retrieve the previous post, to tag as duplicate.

Comment: @EthanBolker I don't get why no one has written an answer using Hyperoperations. This question had been EXTENSIVELY studied on the Tetration Forums already.

Comment: @Brevan: "I don't get why no one has written an answer using Hyperoperations." Be the change you wish to see in the world?

Comment: @Rahul haha, I suppose I can. I spend most of my time on this site reading, not answering, but I suppose it couldn't hurt to throw up an answer like that :)

Comment: @Rahul I went ahead and posted a super short post detailing Zeration. I might expand it a lot later and condense it (shortening the snippets I copied, discussing properties we would expect zeration to have, etc.)

Answer (score 11):

This is a well studied topic in certain circles, and is referred to as Zeration. It is considered the $0$-th level of the extended [Hyperoperation family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation). Often we simply see Zeration simply defined to be the [Successor Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function) as defined in the [Peano Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms).

However, other definitions of Zeration have been studied. A great start is to look on the Tetration Forums; in particular, I reccomend [this post](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=122&highlight=addition). Some snippets from that page include:

> At the very simple common sense level, zeration is an attempt for finding an operation filling the gap in the following operations’ sequence:
>
> $a ^ a = a [3] a = a [4] 2 = {}^2a \implies$ exponentiation $\leftrightarrow$ tetration
>   $a\times a = a [2] a = a [3] 2 = a ^ 2 \implies$  multiplication $\leftrightarrow$ exponentiation
>   $a + a = a [1] a = a [2] 2 = a \times 2\implies$  addition $\leftrightarrow$ multiplication
>
> which should be logically completed by a new operation that we may call zeration (indicating it by the infixed operation sign “$\circ$”) and that should at least have the following “strange” property:
>
> $a \circ a = a [0] a = a [1] 2 = a + 2\implies$ zeration $\leftrightarrow$ addition.

Note that the notation $a[n]b$ is common Hyperoperation notation, ${}^2a$ is [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). I have edited the quotes to add MathJax formatting. The symbol "$\circ$" is your @ symbol. Continuing in that link, we find the following:

> The theoretical way for justifying such new operation is provided by the Ackermann Function. In fact, the definition of Ackermann Function (AF) can be summarised [sic] as follows:
>
> $A(0, n) = n + 1$
>   $A(s, 0) = A(s-1, 1)$
>   $A(s, n) = A(s-1, A(s, n-1))$

Continuing further, we get to the crux of the post

> With the provisional exception of row $s=0$, we could re-define Ackermann’s Function as follows:
>
> $A(s, n) = 2 [s] (n + 3) – 3$, or:
>   $2 [s] n = A(s, n-3) + 3$
>
> For $s=0$ we have:
>   $A(0, n) = 2 [0] (n + 3) – 3 = n + 1$ (zeration)
>   which gives: $2 \circ (n+3) = n + 4$ 
>   therefore: $2 ° n = n + 1$, (for: $n \ge 3$)
>   to which we may add: $2 \circ 2 = 2 + 2$ 
>   and: $n \circ n = n + 2$
>
> We can start using these expressions in order to find out the first properties of the “zeration” operation, which can be described as follows:
>
> $a \circ b = a + 1$ , if $a > b $
>   $a \circ b = b + 1$ , if $a < b  $
>   $a \circ b = a + 2 = b + 2$ , if $a = b$

If you continue reading the page I linked you will find an extensive discussion of other interpretations and definitions of Zeration, including the different properties such a function could be expected to hold (in particular, having an inverse!). Note that much of the Tetration Forums are a contentious subject at best, but seems to be the best treasure trove of information on this topic you will find. Other proposed definitions include
$$ a\circ b =
\begin{cases}
b+1,  & b>a+1 \\
a+2, & b \le a+1
\end{cases}$$
As well as the classic
$$ a\circ b =
\begin{cases}
\max(a,b)+1,  & a \neq b \\
a+2=b+2, & a=b
\end{cases}$$
The second of which is covered in @Hagen's post

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, and the link, that sounds interesting.

Comment: Great answer. I've provided more links in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If we could use multiplication operator '$\times$' and division operator '$/$' to get this @ operator, then

$\underbrace{x@x@...@x}_n=n \times ((x/n) +1)=x+n$ for $n \neq 0,1$.

Discrepancies will occur at $n=0$ and $n=1$ as for $n=1$ we will get $x=x+1$
and at $n=0$, $ x/n$ will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

**There are already amazing answers!**

But I'll try to give some additional info since this question was asked a lot of times in the past (and it will be asked again in the future right?) and I gave some answers too.

---

As **Hagen von Eitzen** and **Brevan Ellefsen** said $$a\circ b:= \max (a,b)+1+\delta_{ab}$$ is one of the solutions of the equation $a*(a+n)=a+n+1$ , where $a$ and $n$ range over some restricted domains.

This particular solution [was called Zeration by Rubtsov and Romerio](https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/attachment.php?aid=251): you can easily find the details of the story in the Zeration thread that was linked by **Brevan Ellefsen**.

Another solution is $\max(a,b)+1$ which is commutative and is not discontinuous, but in the linked thread, a user, Tetration Forum's founder, also noticed that it is possible to find a *non-commutative solution* too.

You can find an updated discussion of the topic in this thread:

[Zeration Update @Tetration Forum](https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=926&highlight=zeration)

Also here at MSE, similar questions were answered: for example, this one is almost identical

[Does anything precede incrementation in the operator “hierarchy?”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170398/does-anything-precede-incrementation-in-the-operator-hierarchy/346004#346004)

and also **remark 1** of this answer I wrote 2 years ago:

[More info on Zeration - Go to **remark 1**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227761/example-x-y-and-z-values-for-x-uparrow-alpha-y-z-where-alpha-in-bbb?noredirect=1&lq=1)