# Layers of operation by repetition and extending them

Tags: functions, arithmetic

So I was sitting extremely bored in class the other day, and I thought about something:

$a \cdot b := \overbrace{a+a+...+a}^{b}$

$a^{b} := \overbrace{a \cdot a \cdot ... \cdot a}^{b}$

$^{b}a := \overbrace{a^{a^{...}}}^{b}$

This can also go the other way:

$a+b := \overbrace{SS...S}^{b}a \, $  (brackets left out for clarity)

However, I could not find any other operators which are defined (or at least started as being defined) as repeating a "lower level operation" (whatever that means).

Is there some sort of function $f:(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that:
$f(a, b, 0) = \overbrace{SS...S}^{b}a$
$f(a, b, n) = f^{°b}(a, a, n-1)$ where $f^{°n}(p)$ denotes repeated appliance of $f$? If so, how can we generalize it to $f(a, b, n)$ $(n\in\mathbb{Z}^{-})$?

Comment: Looks like you are asking about [Extending Knuth up-arrow/hyperoperations to non-positive values](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3194414/318073). Usually, $f(a,b,n)=H_n(a,b)$ is a sequence of [Hyperoperations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation#Definition), or in [Knuth Up-Arrow Notation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnuthUp-ArrowNotation.html), these are Ackermann Numbers.

Comment: @Vepir very interesting comment. I am surprized that it hasn't been commented by the asker.